# Sharing files between PC and remote web server via FTP

Tags: php, web

This may have been asked before, but I could not find the answer.

I am looking to share a folder/files on my desktop/local machine with a specific folder/files on my web server, similar to box.net.
In this folder:

- I can give another person access to this remote folder and we can
  share these files between us.
- All the files will get automatically sent to the server when they are saved on the local machine.
- Both myself and the user can see the files on the remote server.

I could do this manually with FTP, but I only want specific remote folders and to have this automated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a Remote Folder as local using SSH on Linux ...

Both server & local pc must using linux OS ....

This is a great tutorial ...

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu

Hope this to help you